# Unexpected labels when creating bar graph with plotly.js

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js

### Basic Problem

I'm making a bar graph using plotly.js where the x-axis represents dates. Dates are being fed to plotly as strings; when there are only 1 or 2 elements on the x-axis the labels don't match the strings being fed to plotly.

### Context

This is part of a web-application using Flask and Python3, the data for the graph is coming from the Python backend; using console.log() statements I have confirmed that the arrays being given to plotly are as expected.

### Example code that results in my error

```
x_labels = ["2019-01-14", "2019-01-15"]

y_axis = [11, 6]

var trace = {
    type: 'bar',
    x: x_labels,
    y: y_axis,
}

var data = [trace]

var layout = {
    xaxis: {
        title: 'Date',
    },
    yaxis: {
        title: 'Data'
    }
}

Plotly.newPlot(graph, data, layout, {responsive: true})
```

### JS Fiddle Demonstration

http://jsfiddle.net/yjk7r4x1/

### Expected Output

The x-axis should just be showing dates such as Jan 13, 2019, Jan 14, 2019... etc. Instead, it is showing up as 12:00 Jan 13, 2019, 0:00 Jan 14, 2019... and so on. I assume those are meant to represent time, but I don't know where the time is coming from or why it is being displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When defining your X-Axis you can modify it to include a "Type" and set the value to "category". By default, the library looks at the data attempts to determine the type for you if it is not specified. Here are what your changes should look like:

***JFIDDLE***: 
http://jsfiddle.net/xa1uy5dz/

```
<head>
  <!-- Plotly.js -->
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV -->
<div id="incorrect_output" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
  <script>


    graph = document.getElementById("incorrect_output");

            x_labels = ["2019-01-14", "2019-01-15"]

            y_axis = [11, 6]

            var trace = {
              type: 'bar',
              x: x_labels,
              y: y_axis,
            }

            var data = [trace]

            var layout = {
              xaxis: {
                title: 'Date',
                type: 'category'
              },
              yaxis: {
                title: 'Data'
              }
            }

            Plotly.newPlot(graph, data, layout, {responsive: true})
  </script>
  <div id="accurate_output" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
  <script>
  graph = document.getElementById("accurate_output");

            x_labels = ["2019-01-14", "2019-01-15", "2019-01-16"]

            y_axis = [11, 6, 8]

            var trace = {
              type: 'bar',
              x: x_labels,
              y: y_axis,
            }

            var data = [trace]

            var layout = {
              xaxis: {
                title: 'Date',
                type: 'category'
              },
              yaxis: {
                title: 'Data'
              }
            }

            Plotly.newPlot(graph, data, layout, {responsive: true})
  </script>
</body>
```

***Referenced Info:*** 
https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/#layout-xaxis-type